# Dynamically creating objects in Eclipse for debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, bluej

In BlueJ, upon compiling a class, you're able to create a new instance of that class from the Project view (the one with all the boxes). From there, you can run any public method of that class, passing your own arguments, and it will give you the return value. This is all strictly for debugging purposes, not for actually creating a new instance of the class in your code.

How do I do this in eclipse? Is it even possible?

[image: Example from BlueJ]

Answer (score 0):

In Dubugging mode > Variables tab > Right click on any object > Change Value.. > It open the dialog box we can enter the expression to update the current object.